# Flexible attribute handling with xml-conduit

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to use [xml-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.0.3.3) for parsing some very large XML files since it seems to be the only XML library for Haskell that can use [Text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text). Unfortunately my XML file has a lot of attributes for some entities (more than 500!) and I need only a few of these (let's say numbers 5, 55, 265, 421). Therefore it is not acceptable for me to explicitly process all the attributes. The function `ignoreAttrs` is not really helpful because it just discards all remaining attributes.

How can I create some `AttrParser` that allow me to parse only some very specific attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ignoreAttrs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xml-conduit/1.0.3.3/doc/html/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html#v%3aignoreAttrs) to avoid processing the remaining attributes.